# Angular 4 Routing not working within the router outlet, when clicked it open new link in new window and not within router-outlet

Tags: angular, typescript, routes

I am trying to display SuburbDataComponent HTML on DASHBOARD-SIDE-PANEL-COMPONENT.HTML using following code, I have created the path and when I click on  Dashboard, it opens the link in a new window where only SuburbDataComponent.html is displaying and the side panel is not showing.Basically link is not showing within the router-outlet. Can anyone please review the code and see what is wrong with itThanks

```
*************************
    app.Module.ts 
*************************


        import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
        import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
        import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule, } from '@angular/forms';
        import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';        
        import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';


        import { DashboardSidePanelComponent } from './user-dashboard/dashboard-side-panel/dashboard-side-panel.component';
        import { SuburbsDataComponent } from './user-dashboard/dashboard-side-panel/suburbs-data/suburbs-data.component';

        const appRoutes: Routes = [
          { path: '', component: HomepageComponent },
          { path: 'userDashboard', component: DashboardSidePanelComponent },
          { path: 'testData', component: SuburbsDataComponent }
        ];



        @NgModule({
          declarations: [
            AppComponent,
            DashboardSidePanelComponent,
            SuburbsDataComponent

          ],
          imports: [
            FormsModule,
            ReactiveFormsModule,
            BrowserModule,
            HttpModule,
            RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)
          ],
          providers: [SuburbsService, AutoCompleteSuburbs, AuthService, AuthGuard],
          bootstrap: [AppComponent]
        })
        export class AppModule { }

*************************
DASHBOARD-SIDE-PANEL-COMPONENT.HTML
*************************



<div class="sidebar">
          <ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
            <li>
              <h3>My Services</h3>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a routerLink="/testData"><span>Dashboard</span></a>
            </li>

            <li>
              <a routerLink="/userDashboard/sending"><i class="fa fa-paper-plane-o fa-lg userDashIcons" aria-hidden="true"></i> <span>Send</span></a>
            </li>

            <li>
              <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-left fa-lg userDashIcons" aria-hidden="true"></i> <span>Receive</span></a>
            </li>

            <li>
              <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-cart-arrow-down fa-lg userDashIcons" aria-hidden="true"></i> <span>Ecommerce</span></a>
            </li>

          </ul>
    </div>

<div class="container-sending">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
*************************
DASHBOARD-SIDE-PANEL-COMPONENT.ts
*************************
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-dashboard-side-panel',
  templateUrl: './dashboard-side-panel.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dashboard-side-panel.component.css']
})
export class DashboardSidePanelComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}

******************************
SuburbDataComponent.html
******************************

<div class="continerred">
  <h1> I AM A TEST WITH RED CONTAINER</h1>
</div>
******************************
SuburbDataComponent.ts
******************************

import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-suburbs-data',
  templateUrl: './suburbs-data.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./suburbs-data.component.css'],
})
export class SuburbsDataComponent  {

  constructor () { }
}
```

Comment: This does not appear to be a valid route? `routerLink="/userDashboard/sending"`

Comment: i am trying to get the link above  <a routerLink="/testData"><span>Dashboard</span></a>

Answer (score 0):

`routerLink` is a directive that takes an array of parameters and should be used this way:

```
<li>
    <a [routerLink]="['/testData']"><span>Dashboard</span></a>
</li>
```

If you'd have a route like `/testData/:id` then link for id=3 could look like either:

```
<a [routerLink]="['/testData/3']">test data #3</a>
```

OR

```
<a [routerLink]="['/testData', 3]">test data #3</a>
```

Where the second one is recommended to use.

PLNKR: https://plnkr.co/edit/g2vHik92YWMy5yWJa1et

Comment: Daniel, tried that code, it does not work. still when i click on link it opens the part of the target link only. not within the router-outlet. already checked css. still not luck

Comment: Sure it works, I've added a plnkr. Try to reproduce your issue there, so I'll be able to help you more...

Comment: It also should work the way Tayyab mentioned, check this link https://angular.io/generated/live-examples/router/eplnkr.html   , and go for   code:  <a routerLink="/admin" routerLinkActive="active">Admin</a>
 in app.component.ts.  which is given by google team for angular 4 latest router usage.